# Conseguir width y height de una imagen externa con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quiero guardar en unas variables el alto y ancho de una imagen que se carga a través de JavaScript (no librerías, plugins, frameworks, etc.) utilizando su URL.

```
img[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    link = this.parentElement.href;
    var w, h;
    document.getElementById('thread').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div id="lightbox"><img src="' + link + '"></div>');
}, false);
```

Donde la variable **link** es la cadena de texto de la URL de la imagen, la cual quiero utilizar para guardar el alto y ancho de la imagen en las variables **w** y **h** con algo similar a:

```
w = link.width;
h = link.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

En [esta respuesta de SOeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442850/3045491) te explica 3 maneras de hacerlo.

Ya que no quieres jQuery, te recomiendo usar esta:

Primero crea una imagen y se le añade un evento `load` para que muestre sus valores `width` y `height` pero es para que sea visual.

```js
function getMeta(url){   
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", function(){
        alert( this.naturalWidth +' '+ this.naturalHeight );
    });
    img.src = url;
}

getMeta("http://www.imagen.com.mx/assets/img/imagen_share.png");
```

Comment: esto puede ser usado en un proyecto de cordova?

Comment: @JuanSaa supongo que sí